# Monitors : " At each point in time, at most one thread may be executing any of its methods. "

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, theory, producer-consumer, monitor

I've been recently taught, the concept of monitors. My prof, said "only one thread per time can be in the monitor". I am not sure I get this that's why I did my research. Wikipaideia states what i wrote as a title. My book states though, that inside monitor there are queues, for threads  that are waiting , until some defined condition is met. What really confused me is a pseudocode we were given as solution to the bounded buffer problem with monitors.
My question is : **If a process is not stopped by a wait() inside the monitor, does monitor structure guaruntee us that it will be permitted to execute the whole method without being interrupted by a context switch or just that, while it is executing the method nobody else produce or consumer is executing their according method??** .
Because in this, slide:
[image]

It seems like we only wake up a consumer if the buffer was empty, and we just produced an item.
**Everytime a producer that reaches that part of code, has produced an item.** Why don't we signal everytime? I supposed that , we (may) consider that: if the buffer wasn't empty, then they may be "active" consumers waiting, to be resumed because they were interrupted by a context switch, but then I thought to myself is this possible? **Is it possible to be interrupted inside a method (not because you are "waited") but by a context switch?**

Comment: The Ada language provides an implementation of Hoare Monitors known as protected objects. The following URL describes that implementation: https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/95rat/rat95html/rat95-p2-9.html#1

Comment: No.  That is the point in the monitor, is only one thread can be executing in it at a time; so if one is executing in it, subsequent ones attempting to enter must wait for it to leave.   It is a bit subtle that `wait()` causes the caller to leave then later enter the monitor.